# How to wait for data to be completely read from Firestore in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a post collection and it has some documents. I retrieve the data from Firestore with this code:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(AppString.FB_POSTS).orderBy('ts',descending: true).limit(10).get().then((querySnapshot){
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(AppString.FB_POSTS).doc(document.id)
                .snapshots().listen((dataSnapshot) {
              PostData postData=PostData.data();
              posts.add(postData);
            });
          }
          );
        });
        setState(() {


          print(posts.length);
        });
```

`posts.length();` return 0 length of list.
I want to wait to fill a complete list from Firestore and use `setState();`

I'm looking for something like the equivalent of `onComplete` and `onError` listeners in a native Android app.

Note: the connection to Firebase is successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can user [StremBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) or [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) where the widget is built after the data is loaded. So you don't have to use setState.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).